# Best practice Between-2-dates / 2-periods summarize algorithm

Tags: c#, linq

**[Edited and some additional relevant info added]**

I would like to know your best deal with this scenario. Instead of iterating each value (or do sum by groupby), I want one "difference between last/first" method. It may worth mention that missing fields (samples below) are  dynamically added at first (but still, thier appearance is threated as "missing".

Sample, 
The range here conscists of dates (but can be month, minutes, hours).

**Get sum of values between each step in a range.**
Fetchced data to calculate:

```
<missing>
2011-01-02  4.5 user1
2011-01-02  1.5 user2
2011-01-03  4.7 user1
2011-01-03  1.6 user2
2011-01-04  4.9 user1
2011-01-04  1.7 user2
2011-01-05  6.1 user1
2011-01-05  1.8 user2
<missing>
2011-01-06  1.9 user2
2011-01-07  6.5 user1
2011-01-07  2.0 user2
2011-01-08  6.9 user1
2011-01-08  2.1 user2
2011-01-09  7.0 user1
2011-01-09  2.2 user2
<missing>
<missing> ..
```

The values in this table are in cumulative order. Which means they are incremented like a timer that ben started/stopped several times, but never RE-started.

If a range `get 20110101--20110131"` was asked, the method answer `"2011-01-01 3,2"`

If an exact period was asked `get 20110107` was requested, the method would answer `"2011-01-07 0.5"`. The result is 0.5 because `20110708 user1 6.9` minus `20110707 user1 6.5` == 0.4 and `20110708 user2 2.1` minus `20110707 user2 2.0` == 0.1. Then add `0.4 + 0.1` together.

It's going to problem when I want to return a array of calculated last/first values. If I want sum between each day in the given range 20110101--20110131, should the `"sum between last/first value"` be executed on each day in the range.

Result like this

```
2011-01-02  0.3
2011-01-03  0.3
2011-01-04  1.3
2011-01-05  0
2011-01-06  0.1
2011-01-07  0.5
2011-01-08  0.2
2011-01-09  0
2011-01-10  0
2011-01-11  0 ..
```

Missing periods (days) in the range would lead to zero as result. I mean, sum between 20110104--20110105 can't be other then zero (due to missing value). Though, if you take sum between 20110104-20110107, you don't recognize the missing values in between.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I just don't get it. I re-read your question 3 times and it just doesn't make any sens to me. Please rephrase/clarify your intent.

Comment: @Jonas, you can start by explaining how `get 20110107` = `2011-01-07 0.5`. Maybe that will help us understand.

Comment: Yes, oh shit sorry! I was just recognized that. Take (20110708 user1 6.9) minus (20110707 user1 6.5) == 0.4. Then the same for user2 (which is 0.1) then add 0.4+0.1 together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, it's solved but it isn't really a single q&a solution..

Some psudocode,

```
ConsumptionOfRange(List someList, Enum somePeriod)
{
  foreach (var user in someList.groupBy(d=>d.Name)
  {
      MethodToFillGapsInRange(ref someList)

      foreach (var period in someList.GroupBy(d => d.Date.Date))
      {
         // Kind of magic here. Ticks is the "weight" of the period somePeriod.
         // This make query know where in future to look for next valid value.
         var localValues = 
                 (from mv in someList
                  where mv.Date == period.Key 
                  || mv.Date.Date == period.Key.AddTicks(Method(somePeriod).Ticks)
                     select mv).ToList();

         // At this place, call the generic function used to calculate range.
         result.Add(ConsumptionRange(dc));
      }
  }   
}

//That generic function looks like this.
//Called directly calculating differences between big ranges (1000 or a million of records)
public AClass ConsumptionOfRange(List someValues)
{
   AClass grouped = 
        (from d in someValues.OrderBy(d=>d.Date)
         group d by d.Name into gr
         select new VC
         {
            Name = gr.FirstOrDefault().Name,
            Date = gr.FirstOrDefault().Date,

            Value =
              (gr.LastOrDefault().Value
                - gr.FirstOrDefault().Value)
               }).FirstOrDefault();

    return grouped;
}
```

The answer is probably not much of help for another, but maybe some semantics are re-usable for later visitors of this Q. Or maybe I can learn one other lesson to do this better.